# Create an array of sub-arrays with the value of an element and the number of times it has repeated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, unique, repeat

I'm trying to take an array (for an example, an array of years) and then make a new array of sub-arrays which tells, firstly, the unique element in the original array and, secondly, how many time it was repeated.

For example, lets say I start of with an array of numbers `[1999, 1999, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2015]`

I would like my function to return an array like `[[1999, 2], [2000, 1], [2005, 3], [2015, 1] ]`
because the year 1999 was repeated twice, the year 2000 was was not repeated, the year 2005 was repeated three times, etc.

I can successfully make a new array that removes the duplicates, but Im getting some weird behavior when it comes to making my sub-arrays.

**EDIT**

Here was my own faulty solution, in case anyone wants to point out what i did wrong.

```
var populateYearsList = function(yearsDuplicate){

var uniqueYears = [];
for (var i=0; i < yearsDuplicate.length; i++){
 if(uniqueYears.indexOf(yearsDuplicate[i]) == -1){
  uniqueYears.push(yearsDuplicate[i])
} else {
  console.log("duplicate found") };
}
 console.log (uniqueYears)
};
```

I ran into the problem of trying to change `uniqueYears.push(yearsDuplicate[i])` into `uniqueYears.push([ yearsDuplicate[i], 1 ])` and then trying to replace my console.log into some sort of incremented counter.

Comment: what is your code so far and what is the weird behaviour?

Comment: So you want an array containing five arrays. How about pushing objects in the new array like this-> `var filteredArr = [{"year":1999, "amount": 2}, {"year":2000, "amount":1}]`

Comment: @Rhumborl I just edited my entry to show my weird-attempted solution. Whenever I tried to push an array instead of just the year, my loops stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as easy as:

```
var input = [1999, 1999, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2015];

var uniq = [];
input.forEach(function(n){
    if (uniq.indexOf(n)<0) 
        uniq.push(n);
});

var output = uniq.map(function(n){
    return [n, input.filter(function(m){ return m == n }).length]
});
```

> **Quick explanation how it works**
>
> Given the input array, map *its unique version* to the new array with this mapping:
>
> element ---> [ element, *the number of occurrences in the original array* ]

***EDIT NOTE***::  *FIXED the previous solution which might introduced duplicate element.*

Comment: good idea but this will create duplicate entries for 1999 and 2005

Comment: @Rhumborl Good spot. I have then updated the solution accordingly. No more duplication.

Comment: Thanks Tao! It works perfectly!

The first `uniq` part is clear to me. However, with the `output` part of the solution I am a little lost...

We are creating a new array with `map`, that part I get. Can you explain what `input.filter(function(m){ return m == n }).length` is doing though?

Comment: @JeuelyFish Glad it helps you. `input.filter(function(m){ return m == n }).length` this takes only elements which are equal to `n` from the original array. So given `n=1999` you'll get `[1999,1999]` which allows you to count it as the number of occurrences in the original array.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
var input = [1999, 1999, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2015];

function numberOfOccurancesArray (input) {
    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        var currentYear = input[i];

        // if there is an element with the name of the currentYear
        if (result[currentYear]) {

            // increace its prop `count` with 1
            result[currentYear].count += 1;

        } else {

            // if not present, create it
            result[currentYear] = {
                year: currentYear,
                count: 1
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is sample code : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j905u9e2/)

Comment: This is I think a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var years = [1999, 1999, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2015];

var occurences = [];

for(var i = 0; i < years.length; i++ ) {
    var year = years[i];
    if(typeof occurences[year] === 'undefined') {
        occurences[year] = 1;
    } else {
        occurences[year]++;   
    }
}

occurences = occurences.map(function(occurences, year) {
    return [year, occurences];
});

console.log(occurences);
```

**EDIT**: Much faster solution

```
    var results = [];
    var uniq = [];
    var counts = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (i; i < years.length; i++) {
        var year = years[i];
        var indexOf = uniq.indexOf(year);
        if (indexOf < 0) {
            uniq.push(year);
            counts[uniq.length - 1] = 1;
        } else {
            counts[indexOf] += 1;
        }
    }

    i = 0;

    for (i; i < uniq.length; i++) {
        results.push([uniq[i], counts[i]]);
    }

    return results;
```

Comment: I like this! However, as a jr dev, can you explain to me what is happening with the 'occurences.map' ? I followed your solution until that point.          It is a working solution though, so thanks for your answer and time!

Comment: Well I've just tested it and my previous solution is really slow in benchmarks. I assume this is because the length of the Array produced in process ( last key index is 2015 ). I've edited my post and posted much faster solution. Here's the simple benchmark: http://jsfiddle.net/yp8hfxgo/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with functional paradigms, reduce it to a dictionary and then map the keys to a tuple.

```
var yearToCounts = input.reduce(function(counts, year) {
    if (year in counts) {
        counts[year]++;
    } else {
        counts[year] = 1;
    }
    return counts;
}, {});

return Object.keys(yearToCounts).map(function(year) {
    return [year, yearToCounts[year]];
});
```

Comment: Also, you can  idiomatically get rid of `if` : `counts[year] = (counts[year]
|| 0)+1`.